# Typescript error in Visual Studio Code doesn't appear in problems list

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

When I compile my Typescript code in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error in the `TERMINAL` window:

```
> Executing task: /Users/tom/github/beeblink/server/node_modules/.bin/tsc -p /Users/tom/github/beeblink/server/tsconfig.json <

dfsimage.ts:119:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer'.
  Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'SharedArrayBuffer'.
    Property '[Symbol.species]' is missing in type 'Buffer'.

119             Buffer.from(diskImageData, diskImageTrack0Offset + usedTrackIdx * diskImageTrackSizeBytes, TRACK_SIZE_BYTES),
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

Same goes if I build it manually from the terminal.

OK, so there's a problem in my code, and I need to fix it. No problem, I can do this. In fact, I've done it already. I don't need any advice about what edits I need to make.

What I do need some advice about: every single other time I've had a problem in my code, I've been able to use `Go` > `Next Problem` or `Go` > `Previous Problem` to go to the source of each build error in turn. This particular one, on the other hand, doesn't appear to be adding itself to this list, and these two menu options do absolutely nothing. I always assumed this stuff just scraped the terminal output to get file/line/column info, but... maybe not?

I can add more problems to my code, and the `Go` > `Next/Previous Problem` functionality works as expected for those. But it seems to ignore this one specific one.

I want the Next/Previous Problem functionality to take every single build error into account. How do I make this happen?